# Disable popwin temporarily with pop-up documentation

Tags: documentation, popup

Following [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/18771/10269) about automatically displaying documentation in a pop-up window, I decided to give it a try based on existing work on [Popup Help in Emacs Lisp](http://blog.jenkster.com/2013/12/popup-help-in-emacs-lisp.html) and [clippy](https://github.com/Fuco1/clippy.el).

However, I've run into an issue whereby `help-xref-interned` doesn't play nice with `popwin`. When I try to create a temp buffer for `help-xref-interned`, there is a brief flash as `popwin` brings the window up, then quickly dismisses it.

Therefore, it seems necessary to disable `popwin` temporarily, then restore it to its original state. I'm wondering what the idiomatic way to do this is. What I have is below:

```el
(defun *-describe-symbol-popup ()
  "Display full documentation of symbol in a pop-up window."
  (interactive)
  (let ((doc (*-symbol-full-doc (symbol-at-point)))
        (x-gtk-use-system-tooltips nil))
    (if (string-empty-p doc)
        (message "Unknown symbol, or no documentation available.")
      (pos-tip-show doc 'tooltip nil nil -1))))

(defmacro *-symbol-full-doc (symbol)
  "Return a string of the full documentation of SYMBOL, as given by
`help-xref-interned'.

If `popwin-mode' is active, disable it temporarily. The value of
`popwin-mode' is thus always nil, even when the mode is active.'"
  (let* ((sym (make-symbol " sym "))
         (form `(let ((,sym ,symbol))
                  (with-temp-buffer
                    (let ((help-xref-following t))
                      (help-mode)
                      (help-xref-interned ,sym)
                      (buffer-string))))))
    (if (fboundp #'popwin-mode)
        `(let ((old-popwin popwin-mode))
           (popwin-mode -1)
           (unwind-protect
               ,form
             (popwin-mode (or old-popwin -1))))
      ,form)))
```

Can I make this more idiomatic/less verbose?

Comment: Did you consider just disabling popwin for help windows?

Comment: For *all* help windows? No, I want to be able to use popwin to dismiss windows normally.

Comment: Well, ok, in this case I'm not sure what there is to be gained over just hitting `q` to dismiss the window.